# Avoid the first render if width or height is 0

Tags: reactjs

I use [`useSize`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/size) to get the parent dimensions.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-jackson-je28o?file=/src/App.tsx) my simple code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import useSize from '@react-hook/size'
import 'tachyons'

interface TestProps {}
const Test: React.FC<TestProps> = () => {
  const target = React.useRef(null)
  const [w, h] = useSize(target)

  const d = `M 0 0 L ${w / 2} 0 L ${w / 2} ${h / 2} L ${w / 4} ${h / 2} Z`
  console.log({ w, h, d })

  return (
    <div className="w-100 h-100" ref={target}>
      <svg className="ba" width={w} height={h}>
        <path d={d} fill="black" fillOpacity={0.3} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="w-100 h-100 bg-red">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div className="bg-gold" style={{ width: 400, height: 200 }}>
        <Test />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The render is triggered 3 times and the first one has `w=0` and `h=0`.
How can I avoid to render the `<div>s` in that case?
So what I would like to have is to render only if `w!=0` and `h!=0`.
I tried:

```js
if(!w || !h) return null
```

but it doesn't render anything.

Comment: The `w` and `h` is `0` by default, and they depend on the `div`. If the `div` doesn't get render in the first place, the size of it will always be `0`. Thus the `w` and `h` will never be any value other than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). This may help :)

also `if(!w || !h) return null` will be true when one of them is NOT zero, not both. You should use the `&&` operator if you want both to be zero.